# Wordpress plugin installation error

Tags: wordpress, plugin

I'm trying to upload secure-wordpress.1.0.6, and I receive the following error:

> Warning: touch() [function.touch]:
>   open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/abs_path/wordpress/tmp/secure-wordpress.tmp)
>   is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/abs_path/:/abs_path/:/usr/local/lib/php:/tmp/php_upload)
>   in /abs_path/public/www/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 199
>
> Download failed. Could not create
>   Temporary file.

The /wp-content folder and all it's subfolders have 777 permission.

I've added the following two lines to wp-config.php:
putenv('TMPDIR='.ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') );
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH .'wp-content/uploads/');

What else should I try?

I am using Wordpress 3.04 in a PHP 4.49 environment.

Comment: You should ask this at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually needed permissions of 2777.

Answer (score 2):

"open_basedir restriction in effect" means your web host is overly paranoid with security. Find a new web host, and one with php5, too.

And 777 permissions are dangerous. WP never needs more than 755. If you need 777 permissions at that host to do anything, that's another reason to find another host.

And http://wordpress.stackexchange.com is a better place for WP questions.